# WSS 3.0 Cannot create list instance

Tags: sharepoint, list, wss, instance

I have created three features - fields, content types and lists. I deployed the solution and everything was fine. However, I deleted my list instance from the Lists section in my site. Now I cannot create it again. I tried to deploy the solution again but no instance was created. How can that be done?

```
<ListInstance Id="2" Title="My Content List" FeatureId="91F7775A-C3FF-11DF-939A-4D4CE0D72085" Description="This is my list instance." TemplateType="100" OnQuickLaunch="False" Url="Lists/MyContentt">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Deactivate the feature
2. Retract and delete the solution
3. Change the ListInstance Id to a GUID and repackage your solution
4. Add and deploy the solution
5. Reactivate the feature

Good luck!